# After adding file uploader other buttons redirectiong to uploader

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I was trying to make my first blog website

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, session, redirect
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
from flask_mail import Mail
import json
from datetime import datetime
import os


with open('config.json', 'r') as c:
    params = json.load(c)["params"]

local_server = True
app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'super-secret-key'
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = params['upload_location']
app.config.update(
    MAIL_SERVER='smtp.gmail.com',
    MAIL_PORT='465',
    MAIL_USE_SSL=True,
    MAIL_USERNAME=params['gmail-user'],
    MAIL_PASSWORD=params['gmail-password']
)
mail = Mail(app)
```

This the code to edit or add new post:-

```
@app.route("/edit/<string:sno>", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def edit(sno):
    if ('user' in session and session['user'] == params['admin_user']):
        if (request.method == 'POST'):
            box_title = request.form.get('title')
            tline = request.form.get('tline')
            slug = request.form.get('slug')
            content = request.form.get('content')
            img_file = request.form.get('img_file')
            date = datetime.now()

            if sno == '0':
                post = Posts(title=box_title, slug=slug,
                             content=content, tagline=tline, img_file=img_file, date=date)
                db.session.add(post)
                db.session.commit()
            else:
                post = Posts.query.filter_by(sno=sno).first()
                post.title = box_title
                post.slug = slug
                post.content = content
                post.tagline = tline
                post.img_file = img_file
                post.date = date
                db.session.commit()
                return redirect('/edit/'+sno)
        post = Posts.query.filter_by(sno=sno).first()
        return render_template('edit.html', params=params, post=post)
```

but when i added a file uploader:-

```
@app.route("/uploader", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def uploader():
    if ('user' in session and session['user'] == params['admin_user']):
        if (request.method == 'POST'):
            f = request.files['file1']
            f.save(os.path.join(
                app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], secure_filename(f.filename)))
            return render_template('sucess.html', params=params)


@app.route("/logout")
def logout():
    session.pop('user')
    return redirect("/dashboard")
```

now the "edit", and "delete" button stared to redirect to uploader and gives Error:-

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'F:\python\Harry\flask\static\uploaded\'

---

and this error comes when i save new post. it redirects to url "http://127.0.0.1:5000/edit/"

Not Found
The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

Answer (score 1):

after a lot of trial and error i found the answer

in the function "edit" the return statement needed one more argument

```
        return render_template('edit.html', params=params, post=post)
```

here i need to add sno=sno

```
        return render_template('edit.html', params=params, post=post, sno=sno)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that whenever you test your code by posting a new post, you do not upload any images. However, your code embeds an image `img_file` in your template even if you do not specify an image. This image is likely *supposed* to be uploaded to `F:\python\Harry\flask\static\uploaded\` whenever you edit or delete (view) posts. However, because your `img_file = request.form.get('img_file')` returns nothing, there is no file named `''` found in your upload directory, and thus the code returns FileNotFoundError.

If what I've said is correct, you need to check if your `request.form.get('img_file')` returns a valid image string.

```
if request.form.get('img_file'): # edited, isspace() doesn't work
    # Your code here...
```

Obviously there are better ways of doing this, but this is one example.

Comment: actually img_file is not an uploader it just tells to which file to use in the blog... which are already present in static folder

Comment: Have you specified an image in the static folder every time you add a post? If you don't you still have an issue. Providing the html code of the templates you used would help.

Comment: yes i specify file name every time.
and why the edit button redirects to uploader...

Comment: For the file/directory not found error, check if your configured UPLOAD_FOLDER exists.

Comment: Folder exists.... This error I get when I click edit button. It was supposed to redirect to upload folder. By clicking on edit button it has go to edit.html

Comment: If it was supposed to redirect to the upload function, change your redirect to point to the '/uploader/'

Comment: Sorry it was not supposed to redirect to uploader function.